# Session variables is not getting printed

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP backend script where I am creating a PHP Session variable:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
    unset($_SESSION['uid']);
$_SESSION['uid']=$this->_out;
```

In my HTML Script I am using the following way to access it:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
ajax: {url:"euseradd.php",complete : function(){var uid='<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){echo $_SESSION["uid"];unset($_SESSION["uid"]);}?>';alert(uid)}},
......................
} );
```

But I am not getting the value - my alert prints empty value. However when I try to echo the session variable output in WAMP server Apache logs by below way:

```
echo 'Value is ' . $_SESSION['uid']
```

I get an error that **'Notice: Array to string conversion'** - my intention is to log the value in some logs to see whats the value backend is also assigning.

**EDIT:**

I modified the echo statement by below way:

```
echo 'Hello ' . serialize($this->_out);
```

And Now I get the data at browser side like:

```
Hello  a:5:{s:2:"id";i:-1;s:11:"fieldErrors";a:0:{}s:5:"error";s:0:"";s:4:"data";a:0:{}s:3:"row";a:11:{s:8:"DT_RowId";s:7:"row_135";s:2:"id";s:3:"135";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"sdfdsf";s:10:"first_name";s:3:"dsf";s:8:"homeaddr";s:21:"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf";s:5:"email";s:8:"s@jj.com";s:10:"officeaddr";s:24:"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";s:6:"mobile";s:8:"11111111";s:3:"age";s:2:"11";s:9:"chargeamt";s:2:"11";s:10:"start_date";s:10:"11/11/2011";}}{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_135","id":"135","last_name":"sdfdsf","first_name":"dsf","homeaddr":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf","email":"s@jj.com","officeaddr":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"11\/11\/2011"}}
```

I am in need to extract the  value "id":"135" from it.

Actually I cannot use success function for my operation due to some constraint. And cause I am fixing an issue I am writing the code for the issue that I have

**EDIT:**

I tried printing the values like below:

```
echo 'Hello ' . serialize($this->_out['row']['DT_RowId']);
```

I get the below output at console logs:

```
Hello s:7:"row_140";{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_140","id":"140","last_name":"sdfdsf","first_name":"dsf","homeaddr":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf","email":"s@jj.com","officeaddr":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"11\/11\/2011"}}
```

I am not sure what structure of the output is - but how can I extract **"id":"140"** from above. I just guess that "row_140" is not a constant name but rather row_# record number

**EDIT:**

Below is the output of **echo print_r($this->_out);** as requested:

```
Array
(
    [id] => -1
    [fieldErrors] => Array
        (
        )

    [error] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [row] => Array
        (
            [DT_RowId] => row_157
            [id] => 157
            [last_name] => sdfdsf
            [first_name] => dsf
            [homeaddr] => sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf
            [email] => s@jj.com
            [officeaddr] => wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
            [mobile] => 11111111
            [age] => 11
            [chargeamt] => 11
            [start_date] => 11/11/2011
        )

)
1{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_157","id":"157","last_name":"sdfdsf","first_name":"dsf","homeaddr":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf","email":"s@jj.com","officeaddr":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"11\/11\/2011"}}
```

Comment: looks like you're storing an array in session variable. what's in $this->_out?

Comment: It is an array - how do we convert it to string and print to Apache logs?

Comment: you can do `$string = var_export($_SESSION['uid'], true);` and then use `$string` for logging.

Comment: Okay, if you need to extract certain key value from an array, there's no point in converting it to string. you can access the value by the specific key. i'm not sure if i get you right though.

Comment: can you `echo $this->_out['row']['DT_RowId'];` and see what you get?

Comment: This is what I get row_141{"row":{"DT_RowId":"row_141","id":"141","last_name":"sdfdsf","first_name":"dsf","homeaddr":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf","email":"s@jj.com","officeaddr":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww","mobile":"11111111","age":"11","chargeamt":"11","start_date":"11\/11\/2011"}}

Comment: i think it would be better if you include your array structure in the question. try `print_r($this->_out)` for instance and kindly paste the output.

Comment: @OzgurBar Thanks for all the required help I have updated the question with required information

Comment: thank you. according to the structure of your array `echo $this->_out['row']['id']` should give you `157`.

Answer (score 0):

Am not really sure whether I understood your issue. But `session_start()` is supposed to be called at the very beginning of the page in your php script. That is, before printing anything. Because the session headers should be sent to the browser.

When you preform the ajax, don't mix up with the PHP. Send the user details to the PHP script via ajax. Then make the php script return the user id back as the response and then you can use it in your javascript. The page that you get on your browser is actually as an output of the PHP script. I mean, all PHP code in your PHP script would be executed and the output is what you are getting on your browser. So, when your page is executed(accessed from browser), that `var uid = '';` in your javascript will already be having a result of the PHP script. It won't get updated after that AJAX call!

And for the array error, I believe you are assigning an array to the `$_SESSION['uid']`. I think it would be better if you just store the value(ie. the user id) as int or string there in that session instead of array!

Comment: Actually I cannot use success function for my operation due to some constraint. And cause I am fixing an issue I am writing the code for the issue that I have

Comment: So, with that AJAX call what you are trying to do? Send some info to PHP page and then do nothing? It's like saying `I love you` to a girl and, then closing your eyes and ears after that without knowing what she's gonna do next?

Comment: Well I would love to reply this in short - I am using Datatables and Datatables manual says that Ajax success function cannot be overwritten - if we do so datatables will not work

Comment: In that case, I believe, that AJAX call is just for `fetching` of records. If you wanted to add a new record, why not use another ajax explicit call(not inside the fetching one) that will send the data to a PHP page which will insert the record to the db. And for the DataTable that displays the records, do a refresh(ie. re-fetch) so as to update the DataTable with complete new records. Wouldn't that work? Otherwise look at the docs of that DataTable and see if there is some built-in methods or something that will help.

Comment: No - then I have a lot of extra code to do around with lots of dependency. Say a column in db is renamed or deleted or added

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access php variables from jquery like that** 
There is a much simpler solution to your problem just `echo $_SESSION['uid']` to your jquery callback function and access it using jquery some what like this

**useradd.php**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
    echo $_SESSION['uid'];
    unset($_SESSION['uid']);
```

**Jquery**

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url  : "euseradd.php",
        cache: false,           
        success: function(responseText){ 
            alert(responseText); //this should contain your session uid
        }
    }); //end of ajax call
    return false;
```

Comment: Well based upon my latest effort by following up answers if I am hard coding the value to a string like : $_SESSION['uid'] = '001'; I do get the alert with string '001' in my web page. Due to some reasons I cannot make use of AJAX success function